# Tkinter - Text widget shrinks when Scrollbar is added

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm working on the GUI for a simple quiz app using Tkinter in Python 2.7.
Thus far, I have begun to set up my frame. I've put a scrollbar inside of a Text widget named `results_txtbx` to scroll up and down a list noting the player's performance on each question. I've been using `grid` since it's easier for me to manage.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Q_and_A:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)

        Label(master).grid(row = 4)

        results_txtbx = Text(master)
        results_scrbr = Scrollbar(results_txtbx)
        results_scrbr.grid(sticky = NS + E)

        results_txtbx.config(width = 20, height = 4, wrap = NONE, yscrollcommand = results_scrbr.set)
        results_txtbx.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 12, sticky = W)



root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Question and Answer")
root.resizable(0, 0)

app = Q_and_A(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What happens is that when it runs, `results_txtbx` resizes to fit the scrollbar. Is there any way to make it keep its original size using `grid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to use a text widget as the master for a scrollbar. Like any other widget, if you pack or grid the scrollbar in the text widget, the text widget will shrink or expand to fit the scrollbar. That is the crux of your problem.

Instead, create a separate frame (which you're already doing), and use that frame as the parent for both the text widget and the scrollbars. If you want the appearance that the scrollbars are inside, set the borderwidth of the text widget to zero, and then give the containing frame a small border.

As a final usability hint, I recommend *not* making the window non-resizable. Your users probably know better what size of window they want than you do. Don't take that control away from your users.

Here's (roughly) how I would implement your code:

- I would use `import Tkinter as tk` rather than `from Tkinter import *` since global imports are generally a bad idea.
- I would make `Q_and_A` a subclass of `tk.Frame` so that it can be treated as a widget.
- I would make the whole window resizable
- I would separate widget creation from widget layout, so all my layout options are in one place. This makes it easier to write and maintain, IMO.
- As mentioned in my answer, I would put the text and scrollbar widgets inside a frame

Here's the final result:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Q_and_A(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.results_txtbx = tk.Text(self, width=20, height=4, wrap="none",
                                     borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.results_scrbr = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", 
                                          command=self.results_txtbx.yview)
        self.results_txtbx.configure(yscrollcommand=self.results_scrbr.set)

        self.label.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
        self.results_scrbr.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
        self.results_txtbx.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Question And Answer")

app = Q_and_A(root)
app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it somewhat in order to do what I needed. In the end, I made another label to store the box and scrollbar. I will post my code up in the answers for comparison.

I just picked up Tkinter the other day, so I'm still figuring it out. You helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Set `results_scrbr.grid(row = 3, column = 2)` next to `results_txtbx.grid(row = 3,column = 1, padx = 4)`, `sticky` is not needed because window is not resizable, and i lowered the padx so scrollbar is closer to text.

Also to make the results_txtbx vertically scrollable, add `results_scrbr.config(command=results_txtbx.yview)`

Here is a working code...

```
from Tkinter import *

class Q_and_A:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)

        Label(master).grid(row = 4)

        results_txtbx = Text(master)
        results_scrbr = Scrollbar(master)
        results_scrbr.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
        results_scrbr.config(command=results_txtbx.yview)


        results_txtbx.config(width = 20, height = 4,
                             wrap = NONE, yscrollcommand = results_scrbr.set)
        results_txtbx.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 4)



root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Question and Answer")
root.resizable(0, 0)

app = Q_and_A(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

My implemented solution:

I needed to add more widgets to the app, so I bound the `Scrollbar` and `Text` widgets to another label and put that in the proper column the code (trimmed for readability) is below:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Q_and_A(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self)

        #Set up menu strip

        self.main_menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.main_menu, tearoff = 0)

        self.file_menu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.quit)

        self.main_menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.file_menu)

        self.master.config(menu = self.main_menu)

        #Set up labels

        self.question_lbl = tk.Label(self, text = "Question #: ", padx = 12, pady = 6)
        self.question_lbl.grid(row = 0, sticky = "w")

        tk.Label(self, text = "Hint: ").grid(row = 1, sticky = "w", padx = 12, pady = 6)
        tk.Label(self, text = "Answer: ").grid(row = 2, sticky = "w", padx = 12, pady = 6)
        tk.Label(self, text = "Results: ").grid(row = 3, sticky = "nw", padx = 12, pady = 6)

        tk.Label(self).grid(row = 4)

        #Set up textboxes
        self.question_txtbx = tk.Entry(self)
        self.question_txtbx.config(width = 60)
        self.question_txtbx.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 12, columnspan = 3, sticky = "w")
        self.help_txtbx = tk.Entry(self)
        self.help_txtbx.config(width = 40)
        self.help_txtbx.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 12, sticky = "w")
        self.answer_txtbx = tk.Entry(self)
        self.answer_txtbx.config(width = 40)
        self.answer_txtbx.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2, padx = 12, sticky = "w")

        self.results_label = tk.Label(self)

        self.results_txtbx = tk.Text(self.results_label, width = 10, height = 4, wrap = "none", borderwidth = 1, highlightthickness = 1)
        self.results_scrbr = tk.Scrollbar(self.results_label, orient = "vertical", command = self.results_txtbx.yview)
        self.results_txtbx.configure(yscrollcommand = self.results_scrbr.set)

        self.label.grid(row = 1)
        self.results_label.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 11, sticky = "w")
        self.results_scrbr.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nse")
        self.results_txtbx.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "w")

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Question and Answer")
#A note: The window is non-resizable due to project specifications.
root.resizable(0, 0)

app = Q_and_A(root)
app.pack(side = "top", fill = "both")
root.mainloop()
```

I'll keep storage in nested labels as a reference for myself for when I need to group things close together, unless there's some reason it should be avoided. Worked very well here. Thanks to Bryan for the advice.